# Remote view html files in Kendo UI Mobile

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have created an sample hybrid app using telerik app builder CLI. The project loads an initial home screen from a COMPONENTS folder in the project. Now i have Home folder with an index.js and view.html in it and the Home folder is inside Components. I added About folder with an index.js and view.html in it.

Both view.html have a div inside it. Now i need to know how to navigate from home to about. This has to happen from the JS. I tried

```
      var app = new kendo.mobile.Application();
      app.navigate("#AboutView");
```

"#AboutView" is the id of the div in view.html in About folder. This doesn't work. Could someone provide any help

Answer (score 0):

with remote views ... you will need to provide the full path. and the reference is always from the root of the project. so in your case it will be

components/About/view.html

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/application#remote-views